# Dynamic IP Whitelist with mod_rewrite in .htaccess. Condition of allowing all IPs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following block of code that lets anyone who has their IP in the whitelist file "access-list" goes through with access to the directory that holds the .htaccess file. I am not familiar with this syntax and just copied the code from somewhere on this site and this works very well:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap hosts-allow txt:/etc/apache2/access-list
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$ 
RewriteRule .* - [E=Va:%1,E=Vb:%2,E=Vc:%3,E=Vd:%4] 
RewriteCond ${hosts-allow:%{ENV:Va}.%{ENV:Vb}.%{ENV:Vc}.%{ENV:Vd}|black} ^black$ 
RewriteCond ${hosts-allow:%{ENV:Va}.%{ENV:Vb}.%{ENV:Vc}.*|black} ^black$ 
RewriteCond ${hosts-allow:%{ENV:Va}.%{ENV:Vb}.*.*|black} ^black$ 
RewriteRule   ^  sorry.html
```

The access-file has entries in the following config format:

```
#allowed IP addresses

123.123.123.123 - 
109.121.142.109 -
```

Now my problem is some days I want to simply let anyone through, i.e. REMOTE_ADDR not having to be on the allowed IP list. So I want to modify this same code block in a way where if the "access-list" txt file is blank (completely blank with no ip in it: 0 characters), it should not actually deny everyone, but allow everyone.

Right now, whenever, there is one ip or more, it allows those IPs and deny all others. This is okay. If there is no IP (file is blank), it denies everyone. I want this to be allow everyone (i.e. blank file indicating, no access rules are enforced).

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the htaccess file completely (or even better just rename it to htaccess.txt). It should allow acess to everyone. Then if you need to enable at a specific time or day you could just create a cronjob that simply copies the htaccess.txt file to .htaccess lets say saturday at 3pm or whatever.